# Is it possible to permanently alter the title of a command prompt, like it is to alter the 'prompt' value?

Tags: cmd, customization, titlebar

I am aware that it is possible to permanently alter the 'prompt' variable (the command prompt that begins every command line, defaulting to the current drive and path, followed by a greater than sign (>)) in the Command Prompt by adding an Environment Variable named 'Prompt' and setting the value to that which can be set by running the `prompt` command.

However, I am curious to know if it is possible to set the Window Title of the command prompt (this is possible by running `title [insert value here]`), perhaps by setting a parameter in the cmd.exe file settings. Unfortunately I do not know if this is possible, and if so the correct syntax to get it to work. Hence my question here. I have looked in many places for an answer to this question, but I seemingly find only sites with details on command parameters being executed within the prompt itself.

Comment: syntax would be: `title %variable%` The problem is, the variable is not dynamic. If the title is set, it is set (until you set it again explicitly). Changing the variable afterwards does not change the title.

Comment: @Stephan Are you referring the title command within the Command Prompt itself? The title command is session-related, or so I believe, and resets upon close. Which is why I asked the initial question.

Comment: `title` has a parameter `/D`, which suppresses auto-run commands from Registry. So it should be possible to implement a `title` command for new cmd-windows as a autorun command in the registry. But same problem: it's not dynamic (like the prompt).

Comment: @Stephan Hallelujah! I have managed to get it to work, if not dynamically. I had heard of the /d parameter, but mistakenly thought that it was not related, at least in any useful way. This is probably due to the extreme lack of documentation on REG_SZ AutoRun commands. Still, thank you for the information you have granted me via your comments.

Comment: You're welcome. You should post your solution as an answer to this question and accept it, so that other users with the same problem can find it and benefit.

Comment: @Stephan Heh, being new to this site I knew not that I was able to do this. However, here goes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can create a String key in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` named `AutoRun`, with a value for the Window Title. This will a set the title bar of Command Prompt to the value specified in the key.

Comment: Actually, in my PC, running Windows 11, the key in the Registry was not found.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a way to set the title text in Windows 10 using the PROMPT variable itself, since the Windows 10 console host now recognizes [ANSI control codes](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2016/02/04/Windows-10-TH2-%28v1511%29-Console-Host-Enhancements), but it can be a bit tricky. This is the value of my PROMPT variable:

```
$E]0; $p ^G$E[1;37;44m$t$s$p$g$e[0m
```

This gives me a prompt with the time, the current directory and a `>` with bold white foreground on a blue background. It also sets the window title to the current working directory.

`$p` and `$g` you presumably already know. `$t` inserts the time. `$s` inserts a space. $e inserts an ESC character. ([PROMPT documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html))

`$e]0;` begins the ANSI sequence to set the window title. It is ended with a ^G (\007) the BEL character. This is where the tricky part lies. Setting this on the command line is trivial; you can simply type Alt+007 or hit ^G on your keyboard. Setting it in the environment variables in the registry is the hard part. The Windows edit box for environment variables ignores the control codes. I resorted to a .reg file to get it set.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"PROMPT"="$E]0; $p $E[1;37;44m$t$s$p$g$e[0m"
```

The ^G character shows as a square box for me here. You need to get that ^G character into that spot in the prompt string.

See the [Wikipedia article on ANSI codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for more on what you can do with it.

Comment: How do you highlight the prompt? I tried to find but failed.

Comment: @NameError What do you mean? Highlight the prompt in what way?

Comment: The `$E]0; $p ^G$E[1;37;44m$t$s$p$g$e[0m` prompt command makes the prompt text to be white and with a blue background. But what characters given to a prompt command gives the background colour effect?

Comment: Read the linked Wikipedia article. The 44 in the string sets the background color to blue

Comment: You don't need a `^G` character to do this as OSC sequences can be terminated with ``<ESC>\`` (0x1B 0x5C), making that prompt `$E]0;$P$E\$E[1;37;44m$T$S$P$G$E[0m`.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way: Start ---> cmd ---> Right-Click ---> Open File Location ---> Right-Click "Command Prompt.exe" ---> Rename --->  ---> Enter ---> Steps 1-2 ---> Click/Right-Click+Run as administrator.

What to change through Properties

[image]

Permanent change to cmd title when you open it through Start ---> cmd ---> Left-Click/Right-Click+Run as administrator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"CompletionChar"=dword:00000009
"DefaultColor"=dword:00000000
"EnableExtensions"=dword:00000001
"AutoRun"="title Hello &cls"
```

change autorun's value to any command, that always run at the begining. just like**Ædx** said  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Way:

1. Right click on desktop and go to "new"
2. Click "shortcut" and type in "cmd.exe" for file location
3. Title it whatever you want!
   (It will always have the title you selected unless you open it through the "run" box.)

Go to this link below for more help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ